# Returning null for array_agg select using GORM (Postgres SQL - GORM)

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

guys I want to scan array_agg to pg.StringArray element, here's the detail:

Go Struct:

```
type QuestionData struct {
    QuestionSummary string         `json:"question_summary"`
    QuestionText    string         `json:"question_text"`
    Answer          pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:text[]" json:"answers"`
    RightAnswer     string         `json:"right_answer"`
}
```

Query:

```
select mdl_question_attempts.questionsummary as question_summary, mdl_question.questiontext as question_text, ARRAY_AGG(mdl_question_answers.answer order by mdl_question_answers.id) filter (
where mdl_question_answers.answer is not null) as answers, mdl_question_attempts.rightanswer as right_answer
from  "mdl_quiz_attempts"
join mdl_user on
mdl_user.id = mdl_quiz_attempts.userid
join mdl_quiz on
mdl_quiz.id = mdl_quiz_attempts.quiz
join mdl_course on
mdl_course.id = mdl_quiz.course
join mdl_question_usages on
mdl_question_usages.id = mdl_quiz_attempts.uniqueid
join mdl_question_attempts on
mdl_question_attempts.questionusageid = mdl_question_usages.id
join mdl_question on
mdl_question.id = mdl_question_attempts.questionid
left join mdl_question_answers on
mdl_question.id = mdl_question_answers.question
where mdl_quiz.id = 5
group by mdl_quiz.id, mdl_question_attempts.questionsummary, mdl_question.questiontext, mdl_question_attempts.rightanswer
order by mdl_quiz.id asc
```

Result:
[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM1WG.png)

Gorm code:

```
queryquestion := r.db.WithContext(ctx).
        Table("mdl_quiz_attempts").
        Joins("JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_user.id = mdl_quiz_attempts.userid").
        Joins("JOIN mdl_quiz ON mdl_quiz.id = mdl_quiz_attempts.quiz").
        Joins("JOIN mdl_course on mdl_course.id = mdl_quiz.course").
        Joins("JOIN mdl_question_usages ON mdl_question_usages.id = mdl_quiz_attempts.uniqueid").
        Joins("JOIN mdl_question_attempts ON mdl_question_attempts.questionusageid = mdl_question_usages.id").
        Joins("JOIN mdl_question ON mdl_question.id = mdl_question_attempts.questionid").
        Joins("left JOIN mdl_question_answers ON mdl_question.id = mdl_question_answers.question ").
        Where("mdl_quiz.id = ?", quizId).
        Group("mdl_quiz.id, mdl_question_attempts.questionsummary, mdl_question.questiontext, mdl_question_attempts.rightanswer").
        Order("mdl_quiz.id ASC")
```

```
question = queryquestion.
        Select("mdl_question_attempts.questionsummary as question_summary",
            "mdl_question.questiontext as question_text",
            "ARRAY_AGG(mdl_question_answers.answer ORDER BY mdl_question_answers.id) filter (where mdl_question_answers.answer is not null) AS answers",
            "mdl_question_attempts.rightanswer as right_answer").
        Find(&QuestionData)
```

Result as in API:
[answer is not scanned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgvns.png)

As you can see, I need help how to properly scan the array_agg into answer pq.stringArray.